# How to start a function in Tkinter without using buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

So, recently I'v got a problem. In this program I wrote as an example, button activates the "first" function and it adds 1 to a variable "a" and when it turns 3 it should change "b"'s value to 2. And when "b" is equal to 2 it should activate an another function called "second" that should turn this variable into 10 after 1 second. But the function "second" does not work. How do I fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(False, False)

a = 0
b = 0

labelA = Label(text=a, font="Arial 32")
labelA.pack()

labelB = Label(text=b, font="Arial 32")
labelB.pack()


def first():
    global a, b
    a+=1
    labelA["text"] = a
    if a==3:
        b+=2
        labelB["text"] = b
    else:
        pass

def second():
    global b
    if b==2:
        time.sleep(1)
        b==10
        labelB["text"] = b
second()

button = Button(command=first, width=30, text="click to do something")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I was expecting the function "second" to be activated but it does not activate

Comment: `second()` definitely will call the function. Have you considered that `b` might not be equal to the number `2`? After all, you explicitly set it to zero.

Comment: Call `second()` after updating `b` inside `first()`.

Answer (score 0):

Function `second` executes only once on script start. So it won't change `b` to `10`. You can move content of `second` function to the `first`:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def first():
    global a, b
    a += 1
    labelA['text'] = a
    if a == 3:
        b += 2
        labelB['text'] = b

    if b == 2:
        time.sleep(1)
        b = 10
        labelB['text'] = b


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.resizable(False, False)
a = 0
b = 0
labelA = Label(text=a)
labelA.pack()
labelB = Label(text=b)
labelB.pack()
button = Button(command=first, width=30, text='click to do something')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't want to combine them

Answer (score 0):

Because you only call the function `second` once at the beginning of the program. Maybe you can add `second()` at the end of function `first`. And correct the statement `b==10` to `b=10` in function `second`.

Comment: I need to activate the second() function right after the first() without combining them

Comment: You might be able to bind functions `first` and `second` to button click at the same time, if you dont want to change anything in `first`. Sucn as `button = Button(command=lambda: (first(), second()))`

Comment: I've already tried it and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute functions after a certain period of time, you can do so using the `root.after()` function in `Tkinter`. Modified code would be:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(False, False)

a = 0
b = 0

labelA = Label(text=a, font="Arial 32")
labelA.pack()

labelB = Label(text=b, font="Arial 32")
labelB.pack()


def first():
    global a, b
    a+=1
    labelA["text"] = a
    if a==3:
        b+=2
        labelB["text"] = b
        if b == 2:
            #We use root.after() to call the 'second' function directly from the 'first' function if 'b' equal to 2.
            root.after(1000,second) #1000ms = 1s
    else:
        pass

def second():
    global b
    if b==2:
        b = 10 #Here you don't need 2 equal signs
        labelB["text"] = b

button = Button(command=first, width=30, text="click to do something")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note that we don’t use parentheses after `second` when passing it as an argument in `root.after()`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to start a function in Tkinter **without using buttons**

Does this help? It **will activate it automatically**.

- Add `root.after` in `first()` function.
- On `second()` function comment out `global b`, `if b==2:` and
  `time.sleep(1)`.
- On `second()` function, replace `b == 2` to `b = 2`.
- Add `root.after` and `root.update()` outside of function.

Add `if __name__=='__main__':` then called `first()` function then `root.after()`

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(False, False)

a = 0
b = 0

labelA = Label(text=a, font="Arial 32")
labelA.pack()

labelB = Label(text=b, font="Arial 32")
labelB.pack()


def first():
    global a, b
    a+=1
    labelA["text"] = a
    if a==3:
        b+=2
        labelB["text"] = b
        root.after(1000, second)
    else:
        pass

def second():
    #lobal b
    #if b==2:
    #time.sleep(1)
    
    b = 10
    labelB["text"] = b

    
root.after(1000, first)
root.update()

button = Button(command=first, width=30, text="click to do something")
button.pack()

if __name__=='__main__':
    first()
    root.after(1000, first)
     
    root.mainloop()
```

When execute, this will activate it automatically.

Answer (score -2):

```
try this one code it working for me proper
import tkinter as tk

def my_function(event):
    print("Function started")

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a widget (e.g., a canvas) where you want to trigger the function.
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
canvas.pack()

# Bind an event to the widget (e.g., <Button-1> for left mouse click).
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", my_function)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But I need to activate it automatically